# Upload video to Facebook doesn't work with SLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to upload the video to Facebook with following code:

```
- (void)facebok
{
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:@"com.apple.facebook"];

    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"appid",
                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream"],
                              ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                              };

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:options completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
         if (granted) {
             NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
             //it will always be the last object with single sign on
             self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
             NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",self.facebookAccount);
             [self post];
         } else {
             //Fail gracefully...
             NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);

         }
     }];
  }

- (void)post
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *status = @"One step closer.";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"title":status, @"description":status};

    SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                            URL:url
                                                     parameters:params];

    [uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                           withName:@"source"
                               type:@"video/quicktime"
                           filename:[pathURL absoluteString]];
    uploadRequest.account = self.facebookAccount;

    [uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else
            NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    }];
}
```

Fist it ask for the permission to post the video. That is fine but after few seconds it gives me this error:

`{"error":{"message":"You recently posted something that violates Facebook policies, so you're temporarily blocked from using this feature. For more information, visit the Help Center.\n\nTo keep from getting blocked again, please make sure you've read and understand Facebook's Community Standards.","type":"OAuthException","code":368}}`

Am I doing something wrong to post the video on Facebook?

Comment: did you post too much videos for testing?

Comment: @i-Maddy No I uploaded only 2-3 videos

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861615/upload-video-to-facebook-using-facebook-new-sdk-on-ios-6-0) maybe this will help you.

Comment: @i-Maddy I have tried the same but doesn't work

Comment: so this code was working to post 2-3 videos right?

Comment: Nope I tried before with this code NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
 [permissions release]; but its not work perfectly. Sometime it works sometime does not work